# Transform matrix to zero diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a Hermitian positive semidefinite matrix $A$, is it possible to find a unitary matrix $U$ such that $UAU^H$ has zeros along the diagonal?

Comment: If $A = 0$. Otherwise not, $UAU^H$ is also Hermitian, and positive semidefinite. Unless it's $0$, it has at least one positive eigenvalue (and no negative), hence its trace must be positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hermitian matrices with all zeroes along the diagonal are exactly those such that the sum of their eigenvalues is zero; this can be seen by taking the trace. In particular, the only positive-semidefinite such matrix is the zero matrix.